# Как создать копию List<T>?

Tags: c#

У меня есть List внутри которого LanguageSet

```
 public class LanguageSet
    {
        private string _langname;
        private string _isoname;

        public string Langname
        {
            get => _langname;
            set => _langname = value;
        }

        public string Isoname
        {
            get => _isoname;
            set => _isoname = value;
        }

        Dictionary<string, string> langDct = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        public Dictionary<string, string> GetLanguageDictionary()
        {
            return langDct;
        }

        public Dictionary<string, string> SetLanguageDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> dct)
        {
            return langDct = dct;
        }
    }
```

Объявленный List

```
List<LanguageSet> langList = new List<LanguageSet>();
```

Как мне создать List,который будет являться копией *langList*?

Я пытался объявить новый объект и присвоить значение

```
List<LanguageSet> langlist_temp = new List<LanguageSet>()
langlist_teml = langlist;
```

Но потом я понял, что List - это ссылочный тип. Поэтому присвоение одного объекта другому, это просто копирование указателя.

Comment: Конструктор `List` принимает `IEnumerable<T>`, элементы которого она скопирует.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а почему бы не `Clone`? Но в обоих случаях элементы списка тоже ссылочные, а по вопросу непонятно\, что с ними требуется сделать.

Comment: List полностью скопировать, его элементы тоже должны быть скопированы.

Answer (score 6):

Для клонирования того же класса в C# предусмотрен интерфейс [ICloneable](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.icloneable). Реализовав его, вы сможете вызвать метод `Clone()`, который отдаст вам копию объекта.

Реализация такого класса будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
class Test : ICloneable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public object Clone() => MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Заметьте, тут я использовал `MemberwiseClone()`, он сам сделает копию текущего объекта, но не глубокую! Это надо учесть.

Дальше нам остается создать новую коллекцию и перенести в нее копии объектов, что то вроде этого:

```
foreach(var item in mainList)
{
    copiedList.Add((Test)item.Clone());
}
```

Для облегчения этого процесса можно сделать например расширение, которое при помощи того же LINQ в пару строк реализует нам все необходимое:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IList<T> Clone<T>(this IList<T> source) where T : ICloneable 
        => source.Select(item => (T)item.Clone()).ToList();
}
```

Ну и вызываем:

```
var copiedList = mainList.Clone();
```

---

Небольшой тест этого всего:

```
var mainList = new List<Test>
{
    new Test { Name = "Test", Value = 111 }
};

var copiedList = mainList.Clone();

mainList[0].Value = 1;
copiedList[0].Value = 2;

Console.WriteLine(mainList[0].Value);
Console.WriteLine(copiedList[0].Value);
```

Результатом будет два числа (1 и 2).

Comment: Кстати, интересное мнение об [IClonable](https://youtu.be/Dk_ZqdLgLzY?t=451)

Answer (score 0):

*Я пытался объявить новый объект и присвоить значение*

```
List<LanguageSet> langlist_temp = new List<LanguageSet>();
langlist_temp = langlist;
```

*Но потом я понял, что List - это ссылочный тип. Поэтому присвоение одного объекта другому, это просто копирование указателя.*

Все верно. Что бы создать второй список - копию надо сделать так:

```
List<LanguageSet> langlist_temp = new List<LanguageSet>(langlist);
```

Comment: Только это не копия внутренних объектов, с этим надо быть внимательней!

Comment: а что тогда? объясните разницу пожалуйста

Comment: Тут достаточно сделать простой пример, который наглядно это покажет, например [такой](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IKa24a). Внимание на то, что мы не трогаем вообще вторую коллекцию, лишь забираем из нее результат, ну и как видите, результат там не тот, что ожидался. Просто помните, что классы это тоже ссылочные типы, а коллекция просто хранит ссылки. Другими словами, у вас один экземпляр класса в обоих коллекция, если хотите копировать все, то нужно копировать и их тоже, как я показал в своем ответе.

Comment: Понял, спасибо за уточнение.

Если у нас List<int> или List<string> , то создается полноценная копия (т.к. внутри списка значения).
А если List<int[]> или ваш пример, то создается копия ссылки на тот же объект.