# Как добавить в список копию объекта?

Tags: c#, list

Моя проблема заключается в том, что если добавить объект в список, а затем изменить объект в списке изменится и старый объект, т.е. он работает как ссылка. На данный момент мой код работает, но мне приходится передавать все значения старого объекта новому и добавлять этот новый объект.

```
Stat newStat = new Stat();

//передаю все значения объекта
newStat.factor = oldStat.factor;
newStat.maxValue = oldStat.maxValue;
newStat.minValue = oldStat.minValue;
newStat.modifiers = oldStat.modifiers;
newStat.statType = oldStat.statType;
newStat.value = oldStat.value;

stats.Add(newStat);
```

Можно передать быстрее через конструктор, но когда переменных в классе становится больше, это становится неудобно, к тому же не рекомендуется делать больше 2-3 параметров. Есть ли более правильный и простой способ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1034673/220553

Comment: Вы можете передать в конструктор старый объект целиком, а не его поля `new Stat(oldStat)`. Ну и можно `Stat newStat = (Stat)oldStat.MemberwiseClone();`, только обязательно убедиьесь, что оно склонировалось так как вам надо.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я бы предложил все-таки клонирование через перегрузку конструктора, потому что с ICloneable [много путаницы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/536357/12888024). А еще (по-секрету), я бы для данных использовал `record`. :)

Comment: @aepot `ICloneable` - это лишь интерфейс, который говорит о том, что объект может быть клонирован. Не мешают ведь сделать свой, который будет содержать `Clone(true)`, чтоб можно было указывать нужна-ли глубокая копия, ну или интерфейс с двумя методами `.Clone()` и `DeepClone()`. Для чего нужны интерфейсы, я думаю мы с вами прекрасно знаем, ну а если он не нужен, то соответственно достаточно простого метода копии. В вопросе простой DTO объект, который не содержит чего-либо "глубокого" и `ICloneable` тут будет в самый раз. Ну а если нужна "глубина", то ИМХО, сериализация/десериализация в помощь.

Comment: Если у вас такие проблемы, то, возможно, имеет смысл сделать объект неизменяемым (для этого из коробки подойдёт таки record), или хотя бы научить его создавать свой неизменяемый snapshot.

Comment: Спасибо всем, я попробую использовать ICloneable и record.

Comment: @Придумщик игр: Если вы используете record, то реализовывать ICloneable не нужно: `record` умеет себя клонировать через `r with { }`. Впрочем, если ваш класс неизменяемый, вам вовсе не нужно клонировать его.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо учту